# Comparison Of two HTML

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio-2010, itext

I am working on 2 pdf Compare where 1st I extracted PDF to get styles of PDF .PDF styles are extracted and converted to html. then at last I compare 2 HTML text.

For PDF Extraction I used `itextsharp`

Here is the code

```
  this.result.AppendFormat(
     "<tr><td>{0}</td><td>{1}</td><td>{2}pt</td><td>{3}</td><td>{4}</td><td>", 
    Form1.j, curFont, font_size_client, fontweight, fontstyle);
        }
  this.result.Append(renderInfo.GetText());
        }

  public string GetResultantText()
  {
      if (result.Length > 0)
      {
          result.Append("<tr><td></td><td></td>");
      }
      return result.ToString();
  }
```

this is the code where i used for conversion. MY question is one sample PDF i used HTML text book itself for comparison the text .in HTMLbook there were some styles like background color, fontsize got appended to the text . instead of text it took style. Can you please tel me how to extract style. is the method i chosen to compare 2 PDF is wrong. OR any other method.

Answer (score 0):

Once you extracted it to HTML you can use jQuery to get the .HTML() code.

Take a look here: https://api.jquery.com/html/

After that you can compare the two results.